# Error resizing image with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, gd2

i have a problem with resizing image in CI ( i'm new to CI by the way ).
so here is my code :

```
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = base_url()."/uploads/test.png";
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']         = 800;
    $config['height']       = 600;
    $config['new_image'] = base_url().'/uploads/resized.jpg';


    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    echo $config['source_image'];
```

it give me this error :

> The path to the image is not correct. Your server does not support the
>   GD function required to process this type of image.

i'm using MAMP as a server and i see GD enabled on phpinfo.
i also try to echo the image url , and yes its really there.

please help.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of base_url(), try the absolute or relative path for once.

Comment: You can try with relative path, can also take a look here http://philonthe.net/2010/07/codeigniters-image-library/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use relative path and you can try with this one

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
// Set your config up
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
// Do your manipulation
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

Please see [this](http://philonthe.net/2010/07/codeigniters-image-library/) one

Comment: Hello!, Thanks for the answer. you see i already use initialization. so i try using a relative url, something like this (../uploads/test.png) right ? i also add "$this->image_lib->clear();"  after "$this->image_lib->resize();" while now it doesn't give me an error but the image is not resized yet.

Comment: hey, i just change the source url to "./uploads/test.png" and it works, Thanks anyway ! :)